# add list the Search a substring in C#

Tags: c#, list, search, oledb

I'm  create the application, but i have one question.

The client write the name of user in textbox, example 3 letters and search in database(access) and add the database.

Example: User: Rui.
and search in database all nameuser "Rui".

```
//libraries
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= {0}\Teste.accdb", Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)));
        
    List<string> Users = new List<string>();

    
    OleDbCommand STK = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT NºCliente, NomeUser, CodigoPostal, NIF", conexao);
    STK.CommandText = $" SELECT* FROM MyTable WHERE Str(Lista_Pokemon) like '*{textBox1.Text}*'";

    User.Clear();
    //this code is invention, probably is wrong

    for(int d=0; d<Stk.Count()-1; d++)
         User.Add(...);
}
```

If you can help my thanks. This project is c#, net framework and the database is Access 2010. At the moment I dont create the class, but if you need tell my, i need created.

Comment: There is a `comando` and `STK` in your code. Which one do you actually use?

Comment: sorry, stk... My bad @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: Parameterize your queries, that looks vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following code.

The `using` operator is used here to release resources - this is important!

```
var dataSource = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location),
    "Teste.accdb");

var builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
builder.DataSource = dataSource;

var connectionString = builder.ToString();
var sql = "SELECT ..."; // place your query here

using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var users = new List<User>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var user = new User();

            user.ClientNumber = (int)reader["NºCliente"];
            user.UserName = (string)reader["NomeUser"];
            user.CodigoPostal = (string)reader["CodigoPostal"];
            user.NIF = (string)reader["NIF"];

            users.Add(user);
        }
        // return users; // Return data from method
    }
}
```

This class is used for storing user data.
Change the property names and types to the ones you need.

```
class User
{
    public int ClientNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string CodigoPostal { get; set; }
    public string NIF { get; set; }
}
```

And, of course, use parameters in sql queries, as @dovid showed in his example.

Comment: thanks your contribution. But I not use sql, but use access conetion, System.Data.Oledb. And in my project have this error, in  using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) : 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression' ... '.'

Comment: I need change the code, but your solution is better!!

Answer (score 2):

You need create a DbReader and move to next row until end:

```
OleDbCommand STK = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT NºCliente, NomeUser, CodigoPostal, NIF", conexao);
STK.CommandText = $" SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Str(Lista_Pokemon) like '%{textBox1.Text}%'";

Users.Clear();

var reader = STK.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
    Users.Add(reader["Lista_Pokemon"].ToString());
```

Threading user input into the query text is considered a dangerous practice in terms of security and also not logically unsafe.
It is better to act "according to the book" with parameters:

```
OleDbCommand STK = new OleDbCommand();
STK.Connection = conexao;
STK.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblCliente WHERE User like @userParameter";
STK.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userParameter", $"%{textBox1.Text}%")

Users.Clear();

var reader = STK.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
    Users.Add(reader["User"].ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks dude, but have one error in var reader = STK.ExecuteReader(): No value was provided for one or more defined parameters @dovid

Comment: I dont understand, what is the objetive the '@' @dovid

Comment: @Andrezila did you copy my code exactly? which of the two did you use, the first or the second?

Comment: I copy the first code and the second. But have the similar problem. I dont know, why!?!? The second i dont understand the '@' and the first code error in reader. If have any problem i give more information the code!!!

Comment: @Andrezila can you post the table fields?

Comment: [link the image the table](https://prntscr.com/tkdf7l)!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Alexander Petrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5045688/alexander-petrov) and [dovid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271037/dovid), givend the solution to my problem. But i "found" the solution and i send.

```
OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= {0}\Teste.accdb", Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)));

       OleDbCommand STK = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY Id"); 
conexao.Open();
           comando.Connection = STK;

           var reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

var users = new List<User>();


while (reader.Read())
                   {
                       var user = new User();

                       user.ClientNumber = (reader["ClientNumber "]);
                       user.UserName= reader["UserName"];
                       user.CodigoPostal= reader["CodigoPostal"];
                       user.NIF= reader["NIF"];

                       users.Add(user);
                   }
```

```
class User
        {
            public string ClientNumber { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string CodigoPostal { get; set; }
            public string NIF { get; set; }
        }
```